# ¿Cómo editar y eliminar en relaciones uno a muchos con Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, php5, model

Tengo 3 tablas, las cuáles tienen las siguientes relaciones:

Tabla `Events`:

```
public function modalitys()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Deportes\Models\Modality', 'events_id');
}
```

Tabla `Modality`:

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Deportes\Models\Discount', 'modalitys_id');
}
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Deportes\Models\Event');
}
```

Tabla `discount`:

```
public function modality()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Deportes\Models\Modality');
}
```

¿Existe algún método el *Laravel* para editar modalidades y descuentos con *Eloquent*, asi como `sync` y `detach` para relaciones *1 a 1*?

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con editar con eloquent? No lo entiendo según el contexto de la pregunta.

Comment: Saludos shaz, me refiero si existe algun metodo como los que tiene laravel cuando usas los modelos, por ejemplo, find, first, create, sync y otros pero para editar este tipo de relaciones, la mas cercana que he usado es sync pero con relacioes 1 a 1, no con relaciones de 1 a mucho. Ahora la cosa es que lo que quiero hacer es mas complicado pero de momento quisiera saber si es posible de una manera mas sencilla utilizando las herramietas que ofrece laravel. No se si me explico Shaz...

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender muy bien aún, sin embargo, si te refieres a poder utilizar los métodos típicos que usas en las relaciones, la gran mayoría están disponibles para todas, en todo caso, solo tienes que revisar la herencia de la relación que estés aplicando, o simplemente "probar" a ver si está disponible el método o no.